# Why R is not finding the function "oauth"?

Tags: r, oauth

I am trying to run the function "oauth" from "tuber" but I keep getting this error:

could not find function "yt_oauth"

I am working on the latest version of R Studio. I installed all packages before running this function.
I am following the instructions from this website (the text is in Portuguese, but the code...well, the code is the code ;)
https://daslab-ufes.github.io/meteoro-post/

Thank you for any light you can shed on this... it's driving me crazy.

Comment: You may have installed the packages, but you also need to load them. Use `library(tuber)` in each R session where you want to use the package.

Comment: I got it solved!

Comment: Thank you, Mr. Flick, that's what a co-worker said at the same time you were answering and it did it - such an easy fix!